# ERROR BasicEndpointCaller

Tags: web8

I'm trying to configure an application with XPM.

But my application returns an error 500.

That is my application's cd_core.log:

2016-04-05 12:56:03,415 INFO  ClientSessionManager - Cleanup of expired preview session for machine name: MachineName1 started.
2016-04-05 12:56:03,415 INFO  ClientSessionManager - Cleanup of expired preview session for machine name: MachineName1 started.
2016-04-05 12:56:03,415 DEBUG DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetExpiredPreviewSessionsFunctionImport]
2016-04-05 12:56:03,415 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://localhost:8083/client/v4/content.svc/GetExpiredPreviewSessionsFunctionImport
2016-04-05 12:56:03,417 ERROR BasicEndpointCaller - Exception when getting Input Stream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getInputStream(BasicEndpointCaller.java:251) [odata_client-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:218) [odata_client-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.callEndpoint(BasicEndpointCaller.java:80) [odata_client-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
        at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getODataResponse(DefaultODataClient.java:141) [odata_client-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
        at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getEntity(DefaultODataClient.java:69) [odata_client-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
        at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getEntitiesFromStorage(ContentClient.java:238) [content-client-api-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
        at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getEntityFromDataStore(ContentClient.java:214) [content-client-api-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
        at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getEntity(ContentClient.java:162) [content-client-api-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
        at com.sdl.web.preview.client.session.ClientSessionManager.performCleanup(ClientSessionManager.java:123) [cd_preview_content_client-8.1.0-1241.jar:8.1.0-1241]
        at com.sdl.web.preview.client.session.ClientSessionCleanerMonitor.run(ClientSessionCleanerMonitor.java:50) [cd_preview_content_client-8.1.0-1241.jar:8.1.0-1241]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
2016-04-05 12:56:03,417 ERROR BasicEndpointCaller - Exception when getting data from service endpoint
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168) ~[na:1.8.0_31]

I have my discovery service in another machine. I have configured all services with IP not with 'localhost'.

2nd EDITION:

I can access to discovery via Postman. Also I can do Telnet from my web server to Discovery (server and port).

Could anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error suggests a connectivity issue ("Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect"). Can you double check connections between services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have changed the discovery services to another machine, as you said, then probably some of the capabilities remain unchanged in the discovery database.

Try checking the capabilities registered with

```
java - jar discovery-registration.jar read
```

There you may find your "http://localhost:8083/..." reference, and update it to your IP or hostname url.

If you have deleted some of the capabilities and you have run the registration tool with the `update` option, this doesn't remove the deleted capabilities.

As it is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-0CD121B5-013E-4A03-9DDF-76B7C80C4A86#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Ddiscovery%255C-registration.jar&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1459875442953&currentQuery=discovery%255C-registration.jar&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F.xml&docid=GUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false) you have to run the discovery tool with the `sync` option to update and remove the deleted capabilities  but this "**sync**" option must be available in some patch, because I don't have this option.

Comment: Exactly! when I executed the command that you say, I can see some services with old configuration. I solved the issue                                                                            Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Raúl. As you say, in the last update Sync option was modified to delete capabilities:                                                                        Improved Capability management
The sync command in the Capability registration tool enables you to delete Capabilities from the registry.